# How can I change the icon of the %SystemRoot% folder (C:\Windows)?

Tags: windows, icons, customization

I am trying to change the icon that shows for the System Root, C:\Windows. I can't customize it like you normally would a Windows folder. I have looked for a registry entry I could add a DefaultIcon key too, but I haven't found anything.

I have tried using a desktop.ini file to do it, but it won't work:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=icon.ico,-0
```

The desktop.ini file and that icon were both in the Windows directory and it didn't change it, but those same pieces worked fine in the Downloads folder, so the code works.

Whatever the solution, I would like to avoid using any program to accomplish this.

I also would like to add a custom Icon to the "Program Files" folder and encounter the same issues.

Edit: I assumed, but in case there is a question: I am running Windows 7 (32 Bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the `desktop.ini` file into `C:\WINDOWS` like you did, then run `Command Prompt` as *Administrator* to type below command.

```
ATTRIB +R C:\WINDOWS
```

Comment: Works on windows 10 x64 too, just make sure windows folder is not hidden. Hidden folder did not change icon.